# Ta-lib - Python - MACD Histogram plots Line instead of Histogram

Tags: charts, matplotlib, finance, python-3.3

Ta-Lib for Python - version:0.4.7.

**Issue: Talib.MACD - Histo plotting line instead of histogram**

Python 3.3.2
Matplotlib 1.2.1, Numpy 1.7.1!
OS: Windows 7

**I am trying to add MACD, using Ta-lib.  The histogram is plotting as Line instead of histogram. Need your guidance to sort it out.**

(I tried to attach the image, but unable to do so due to lack of reputations.)

I am very much a fresher to programming and to Python as well as to other packages I am using. Your guidance will help me improve further.

My code:

Calculation:

```
macd = macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(r.close, 12, 26, 9)
```

Plotting:

```
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(211, frameon=True)
    macd = ax1.plot(macd, color='green')
    macd = ax1.plot(macdsignal, color='red')
    macd = ax1.plot(macdhist, color='blue')
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Suresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what Talib or MACD are, but I think you just need to replace your `ax1.plot()` with `ax1.hist(macd, bins=50)`. There are a bunch of options but provided `macd` is just the set of data you want to bin and put into a histogram this should work.

The matplotlib documentation has enough to get you going an example:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot

you will need to Ctrl-f to find `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`.

If instead your `macd` is already binned then you may need to use `ax1.bar()` instead:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your prompt reply. I will check and update you. Kind of you.